# When you connect your phone to a public wifi, is it possible for someone to see your photos being uploaded to iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

When your phone backs up the photos, can someone see the photos?

Comment: Public WiFi are not safe. If you are in some coffee shop that provides the "Public" WiFi, they could see if the wanted to. Certainly do not use them for confidential transactions. http://www.cnet.com/how-to/tips-to-stay-safe-on-public-wi-fi/

Comment: @Buscar웃 that raises a question I don't even know how to google [& my google-fu is pretty good;) - is an encrypted transmission over an unencrypted network significantly more compromisable?

Comment: @Tetsujin I do not know, but I would not log in to my bank sitting in some coffee shop in a questionable neighborhood. Simple thinking, you are connecting to a router provide by the coffee shop. So who ever has the access/control to that router can do pretty much anything. Back to the OP, would somene go true the effort just to see the pictures, I doubt it (but it depends on the pictures :), Remember the Snowden effect, they can pretty much monitor anything.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, no.

Essentially, not only is the transmission encrypted -  see
[iCloud security and privacy overview](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202303)
but also since iOS 8 your phone [changes its MAC address pseudo-randomly](http://www.imore.com/closer-look-ios-8s-mac-randomization), so it can't even be identified as 'your' phone for a lot of the time.

Every time a new potential exploit is discovered, there will be an update to close the door on it - see [About the security content of iOS 8](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201395) for some eye-glazing detail… ;)

Some of this is not actually published by Apple, as the last thing they want to do is give away how they are trying to ensure your security.

Comment: So they can? They just can't see who's phone?

Comment: Do you have a source for the MAC address thing? I always thought the MAC address is more or less hard-wired in a wifi-card (or whatever interface).

Comment: @Zachary As Tetsujin stated, the transmission is encrypted.

Comment: I added some quick links

Comment: The way he explained it made me think someone can see your photos being uploaded, but not who's phone it came from

Comment: encrypted + random MAC addy - makes it harder than hard to intercept

Comment: @oarfish Each network interface has a MAC address permanently assigned to it. However, software can spoof that address. In the case of iOS 8, the device sends out random spoofed MAC addresses to each access point it encounters while scanning for networks. Once you decide to connect to one, iOS sends the actual MAC address to that access point.

Comment: Oh okay. So since its encrypted they can't see it. And since it generates random IP addresses they can't tell who it came from either. That includes the system administrator?